# how can a buyer and vendor can video chat with each other

Tags: magento2, plugin, vendor

i'm creating a magento 2 store in which my client want me to add a feature where a buyer can video chat with the vendor regarding product details. Can any one tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Video chatting is not sure about it but here I gave you text chat for free. You can use your mobile to text chat with your website visitors. https://www.tawk.to/